# FindContours not detecting light colored points

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour

I am trying to detect points from a scatter plot and get the location of those points. For that I am trying to use OpenCV `findContours` function, but for some reason, its not able to detect and draw contours for light colored points on the graph

Here's my code-

```
img = cv2.imread('808.png')
imgGray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# finding contours/shapes
_, threshold = cv2.threshold(imgGray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
  
# using a findContours() function
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(threshold, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

i = 0
  
# list for storing names of shapes
for contour in contours:
    if i == 0:
        i = 1
        continue

    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(
        contour, 0.01 * cv2.arcLength(contour, True), True)

    cv2.drawContours(img, [contour], 0, (0, 0, 0), 5)
  
    # finding center point of shape
    M = cv2.moments(contour)
    if M['m00'] != 0.0:
        x = int(M['m10']/M['m00'])
        y = int(M['m01']/M['m00'])
  
cv2.imshow('shapes', img)
  
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And here are the results - 1st is the input and 2nd is the result
[image: input_image]

[image: output_image]

As seen clearly, the function detects and draws correct contours around dark colored points but the light colored points are not getting detected properly. Any help on this or in general the method to do the entire (detecting points and then getting the values from scatter plots) will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: well why do you pick your threshold like that then?

Comment: findContours uses white regions on black background. You are not inverting your threshold. Also, at threshold=128, you are making the gray circles white, so same as the white background.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz - I used those values, thinking that since we are using greyscale images, the values would be between 127 and 255. I am doing something wrong here as mentioned by user fmw42, will try what they said, till then, it would be great if possibly you can give some more ideas on making the code right.

Comment: @fmw42 just to clarify by inverting you mean that I should invert the grayscale image and then use it on the threshold function and so on, right?

Comment: You can threshold before or after inverting your image. The result of the threshold must be white objects on black background. The contours will be found on the white regions. You like just need external contours Some of your gray and black circles look like they overlay, They will get merged into one contour unless you do something like watershed processing to separate them. You may want to use connected components processing rather than contours. But either should work, esp if your dots do not overlap. See the contour documentation about the polarity it wants.

Comment: To use external contours, you would like need to remove the axes and grid lines and legend, etc.  So you may still be better using all the contours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's your threshold level. It's too low. Always inspect your intermediate values.

after BGR2GRAY:

[image: gray]

after thresholding at 127:

[image: threshold 127]

Pick a higher threshold, say 192:

[image: threshold 192]

**Now** you've got them all.

Comment: do also pay attention to the other comments telling you to invert. you can do that in the threshold() call itself passing `THRESH_BINARY_INV`. contours/components are white-on-black.